# Count while have OR in condition

Tags: sql-server

Trying to count how many patients have a certain type diagnosis, this should return 3, but its returning 5 so wondering if there is a way I can count one column for multiple conditions?

```
SELECT COUNT(Diagnosis_1) AS '85th %'
FROM   PROBLEM
WHERE  ENCOUNTER_DATE BETWEEN '01/06/2016' AND '01/06/16'
       AND DIAGNOSIS_1 = '27800'
        OR DIAGNOSIS_1 = 'V8553'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are missing parentheses in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Check about priority of logic operations and data format (`'01/06/2016' == '01/06/16'`):

```
SELECT COUNT(Diagnosis_1) AS [85th %]
FROM PROBLEM
WHERE ENCOUNTER_DATE = '20160601'
    AND DIAGNOSIS_1 IN ('27800', 'V8553')
```